# Moving each javascript item separately

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2010

I'm using a Carousel example from [this](http://www.enova-tech.net/lab/jmycarousel/1) website.
For one single carousel on the page it works well, but when I have multiple carousels on the same page, it shows navigation buttons only for the top carousel, and when the top one moves, all the other move along.
I am trying to make each one of them move independently...

```
              <script src="/Scripts/jMyCarousel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
              ...

             foreach(something)
             {
              <div class="jMyCarousel">
                 <ul>
                    <li>image1</li>
                    <li>image1</li>
                    ...
                 </ul>
              </div>
             }
              ...

             <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                $(".jMyCarousel").jMyCarousel({ visible: '50%', eltByElt: true });
                });
             </script>
```

As far as I know, if in the script (the last part) I'm using the class (for example ".jMyCarousel") it should create a new carousel for each item that has this class name.. but here it isn't the case.

Any idea how to make each carousel independent?

Comment: Can you give the divs id's and then use the id in the jquery. e.g #jMyCarousel2

Comment: What do you mean? give them all the same id and use it instead of the class name?

Comment: I dont want a post an answer for the fear of a downvote because this is just a guess but cant you just go <div id="jMyCarousel1"> ... <div id="jMyCarousel2"> and then have jquery event for each div $("#jMyCarousel1").jMyCarousel({ visible: '50%', eltByElt: true });etc...

Comment: The problem is I don't know how many divs I will have.. it comes from a foreach loop. giving a class name should basically resolve it, but it doesn't :(

Comment: Don't use the selector 'as is'. That's not a true iteration. Use an iterator and for each loop apply the behaviour. Example: $(".jMyCarousel").each(function(){ $(this).jMyCarousel({ visible: '50%', eltByElt: true });});

Comment: @Pablo! thanks!!! it worked!!! :)))))) it's not an "answer", so I can't pick it... but it solved everything! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the selector 'as is'. That's not a true iteration. Use an iterator and for each loop apply the behaviour. Example:

```
$(".jMyCarousel").each(function(){ 
    $(this).jMyCarousel({ visible: '50%', eltByElt: true });
});
```

I posted my comment as an answer so you can close the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Found this link for you

[Image carousel 1.0.3 is out](http://forum.cmsmadesimple.org/viewtopic.php?t=21877)

They have demo of multiple instances here

[demo page](http://www.enova-tech.net/app/webroot/files/jMyCarousel-test/)

Code from inspecting demo page:

```
    $(function() {
        $(".JMyCarousel#carousel1").jMyCarousel({
            visible: '100%'
        });
        $(".JMyCarousel#carousel2").jMyCarousel({
            visible: '4',
            eltByElt: true,
            evtStart: 'mousedown',
            evtStop: 'mouseup'
        });
        $(".JMyCarousel#carousel3").jMyCarousel({
            visible: '3',
            auto : false, 
            vertical : true,
            speed : 500
        });
    });
```

I know that you dont know how many divs there are going to be, so this will be an issue for you.
Cant you dynamically create ids?